# How much bonus damage and sign intensity does the Focus talent provide?

Tags: the-witcher-3

The Focus talent has the following description:

> Adrenaline points increase both weapon damage and sign intensity

This sounds like a really useful talent, but slots are very rare and putting one of the neutral talents in a rare slot is quite an investment, especially as they don't provide any bonus to mutagens. To judge wether this is worth it it would be necessary to know the size of the bonus damage and sign intensity.

How high is that bonus exactly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Witcher Wiki](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Focus), it's 10% per adrenalin point.

> Effect
>       Adrenaline Points also increase your Sign damage. 10% Sign Intensity per Adrenalin Point.

Comment: Lets say I've 100 sign intensity, does 3 points then mean I have 130 (+30%) or 133,1 (100 + 10% = 110 + 10% = 121 + 10% = 133,1)?

Comment: +% to sign intensity stacks additively, e.g. 100 +10% +10% +10% = +130%. Incidentally, I can't think of anytime, game or real life, when bonus percentages are computed as each is added, like in your example. Most of the time, they either stack additively or multiplicatively (all the bonuses are multiplied together like 1 - (1-.1) * (1-.1) * (1-.1) = 27%)

Comment: Sooo the bonus damage for swords is 0%? Game tooltip is somewhat misleading then.

Comment: For.sword, you need another perk, if i remember correctly.